# When is the optimizer of $\mathbb E[X]$ and $\mathbb E[X^2]$ the same?

Tags: optimization, expected-value

Consider a non-negative random variable $X\sim p(\theta)$, that is, following distribution $p$ parametrized by $\theta$.

Suppose we find a value of the parameters $\theta^*$ such that $$\mathbb E_{X\sim p(\theta)}[X]$$ is minimized.

- Is $\mathbb E_{X\sim p(\theta)} [X^2]$ minimized for these
  parameters as well?
- Otherwise, what might be sufficient and/or necessary conditions?
- Does it make a difference whether $X$ is a function of $\theta$?

  - **Edit**: As kindly pointed out by whuber in the comments, $X$ is already a function of $\theta$, so assuming arbitrary variables/functions this last question is uninteresting.

Comment: Why would you want to minimize the mean?

Comment: I don't. I want to know which $\theta$ minimizes it.

Comment: Your question is so nonspecific that the  solution is unlikely to be enlightening: if you consider the functions $f_1:\theta\to E_\theta[X]$ and $f_2:\theta\to E_\theta[X^2],$ and let $\Omega(f_i)$ be the set at which $f_i$ attains a minimum, it is necessary and sufficient that  $\Omega(f_1)\cap \Omega(f_2)$ be nonempty. There is no simplification possible.  This abstract characterization makes it easy to construct counterexamples to your first bullet.  The third bullet makes no sense, because $X$ *does* explicitly depend on $\theta$ and if it did not, there wouldn't be any question to ask.

Comment: @whuber With regards to the third bullet, now I realize that for arbitrary $X$ there is no difference. That is a valid answer. Your first comment is essentially a rephrasing of my question, and the answer you give is wrong.

Comment: Could you explain what part of it you think is "wrong"?  It's hard to see how it could be mathematically incorrect, so apparently we're discussing how to interpret your question.  I agree my comment was essentially a rephrasing of your question: that's because the question is so nonspecific in the first place that there's nothing constructive that can be said in general.

Comment: That set being nonempty is necessary but not sufficient. I can find a minimizer of $f_1$ outside the intersection. I found gunes' answer to be quite constructive.

Comment: @whuber $X$ need not be a function of $\theta$. The *distribution* of $X$ is a function of $\theta$. For example, consider the measurable space $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$, let $X$ be the identity map, and $P_\theta$ a distribution indexed by $\theta$. I can keep $X$ fixed while still varying the distribution of $X$ through $\theta$.

Comment: @guy Yes, if you choose to look at it that way (and it's a good point of view) you can assert "$X$ is not a function of $\theta$."  This only shows to what extent the language in the question is ambiguous and confusing, though.  The question really concerns distributions only, because everything in it depends only on the distribution (via the expectations) and not on $X$ at all. Thus the distinction you are making, although correct, isn't really suitable in this context.

Comment: Bronco, the possibility that you can find a minimum of $f_1$ outside the intersection reveals that the answer to the first bullet is "no."  The advantage of my somewhat abstract restatement of your situation is to make the answers obvious.

Comment: @whuber It gives a hint at what one might look for, I think. For example, if $X$ is a strictly positive scale family and $\theta \ge a > 0$, thinking in terms of $X$ being a function of $\theta$ makes it clear that the optimal $\theta$ is the same for both. That suggests something like positive support and stochastic ordering in $\theta$ might give some possible avenues to explore.

Comment: @guy Yes, that gives you a way to think about it.  But the question is framed so generally that such investigations will reveal only a narrow part of the possibilities, I suspect.  You might want to begin by contemplating families of distributions that have exactly two elements, for instance., because they are so simple.  In that setting the question concerns the relationships of two points in the plane: $(E_{\theta_i}(X), E_{\theta_i}(X^2))$ for $i=1,2.$  A quick sketch will provide answers to the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **partial** answer actually. For the first *subquestion*, the optimizers are different, and an example should suffice I guess:

Let $X$ be a RV such that it is $\sim\text{Bern(1/3)}$ with probability $\theta$, or equal to $1/2$ with probability $1-\theta$. $E[X]=\theta/3+(1-\theta)/2$, which is minimized when $\theta=1$. However, $E[X^2]=\theta/3+(1-\theta)/4$ is minimized when $\theta=0$. So, the optimizers for $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$ yield different $\theta^*$.

Here, I don't have an answer for the sufficient/necessary conditions where they're equal; and I'm not sure if it can be found or not.

For your *last* question, if $X$ is a function of $\theta$, then $\theta$ should be a random variable. But, we treat it as if it is an unknown constant and can be set to any value (based on its domain) depending on your objective function (e.g. minimizing $E[X]$). I can't make sense of the situation where $X=f(\theta)$, and we set $\theta$ to optimize $E[X]$.

**Note**: I think your notation should be $\mathbb E_{X\sim p(\theta)}[X]$; i.e. the subscript should use $p(\theta)$ instead of $p(\theta^*)$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It's apparent that it doesn't hold in general, although it seems reasonable to expect it might for a not-too-narrow class of R.V.s.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it shows that the general case does not hold, which was the main point of my question. Carlos Campos' answer provides interesting insight on the second point, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exhaustive answer, actually some hints for the second point:

For minimizing the mean (Using Leibniz rule):
$$\left. \frac{d}{d \theta} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim p(\theta, x)} [x]  \right\lvert_{\theta^*}= \int_{0^{+}}^{\infty} \left. \frac{\partial p(\theta, x)}{\partial \theta} \right\lvert_{\theta^*} x dx  = 0 $$
And for minimizing the second moment:
$$\left. \frac{d}{d \theta} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim p(\theta, x)} [x^2]  \right\lvert_{\theta^*}=  \int_{0^{+}}^{\infty} \left. \frac{\partial p(\theta, x)}{\partial \theta} \right\lvert_{\theta^*} x^2 dx  = 0 $$
Combining both, we found next two sufficient conditions:

- $\left. \frac{\partial p(\theta, x)}{\partial \theta} \right\lvert_{\theta^*}  = 0 \quad \forall x$. For example, a uniform distribution $p(\theta,x) = \mathbb{U}_{[0,\theta]}(x)$ when $\theta \rightarrow 0$
- $\left. \frac{\partial p(\theta, x)}{\partial \theta} \right\lvert_{\theta^*}$ is a function (not a probability distribution) whose first and second central moments are null. I can not find an example.

Union of both sufficient conditions should be the necessary condition.